# Can two people generate the same exact wallet or seed phrase

Tags: wallet, address-generation, seed, key-collision

Can 2 or more people generate the same exact wallet. And if so, what happens then?

Comment: Also see: [Is each Bitcoin address unique?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8804/121614) [How does the Bitcoin protocol deal with address collisions in wallets?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/102804/121614)

Comment: Thanks @VojtěchStrnad, I voted to close as a duplicate and also added the other two questions you proposed to the duplicate targets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. One of them would spend the coins if it happens.

Recent example: https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2023-39910

Comment: It's only realistically possible with broken random number generation.